# Call element inside list of list by index nth

Tags: python

This must be a very basic question, so please bear with me. I have a list of lists like this:

`l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]`

I want to access the `index = 6` then get `output = 7`.

Comment: Can you share some of the approaches you have tried? Or do you have any intuition as why your code would not be fast? Stackoverflow is supposed to help you with *guidance towards* an answer, not generate one *for* you

Comment: Hi team, please calm down, currently I need your avise to improve the code. Just share your opinion

Comment: Your way looks fine to me

Comment: I am looking for any package can do the job faster?

Comment: I am looking for any package can run faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, did not see that you want to find first and second position of sublist.

Then you can merge it inside a list comprehesnsion. Time Complexity is `O(N)`.

```
s =  [5,6]
A=[[1,2,3,4],
   [5,6,7,8],
   [9,10,11,12]]
print([index for index,lst in enumerate(A) if lst[:2]==s][0])
```

Result:

```
1
```

But if your list is increasing by its first index. You can use Binary search to achieve `O(log(N))` time complexity.

Comment: Doesn't work for this case: `A=[[6,2,5,4],
   [5,6,7,8],
   [9,10,11,12]]`

Comment: @ ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000, sorry, changed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
s= [9,10]
a2 = next(c for c,e in enumerate(A) if e[:2]==s)
```